# Parsing XML-like document with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I try to parse the XML-like structure of an EPUB index with `PHP` `DOMDocument` as

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$xml = '
      <navPoint playOrder="1" id="np-1">
        <navLabel>
          <text>I</text>
        </navLabel>
        <content src="/1.html"/>
      </navPoint>
      <navPoint playOrder="2" id="np-2">
        <navLabel>
          <text>II</text>
        </navLabel>
        <content src="/2.html"/>
      </navPoint>
';

@$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>
<html><head></head><body>' . $xml . '</body></html>');

$output = $doc->getElementsByTagName('navPoint');

print_r($output);
```

but it returns

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 0
)
```

What did I do wrong that it does not parse it as a straightforward HTML document?

P.S. I tried PHP XML parser too, but as it is not an actual XML document, it gives errors because of an invalid XML. Therefore, I prefer to treat it as an HTML document.

Comment: HTML is case insensitive, but XML is case insensitive. That is why loadHTML() will convert all tags to lowercase. Your call will not match.

Comment: @ThW excellent point to remember. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`loadXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php), not `loadHTML`.

No need to surround everything with HTML tags, just add a dummy `<root>` item instead, because any valid XML document must have one (you can also add it to the `$xml` variable itself).

Also, using `@` before function calls should be avoided in 99% cases, it prevents you from seeing/understanding what's wrong.

The following should do it:

```
$doc->loadXML('<root>' . $xml . '</root>');
```

**Demo here: https://3v4l.org/s8QvM**